# Video player controls go over the navigation bar

Tags: html, css

So I have this site where I have a sticky header. This site also contains a video. When I scroll down and go over the video, the video controls go on top of the header. So I want the header to be over the video controls instead.

```css
.header {
 padding: none;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 /*border: 1px dashed orange;*/
 position: fixed;
 height: 90px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #005a84;

 overflow: hidden;
 top: 0;

 list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<div>
    <li href="#top"><img src="act_logo.png"></li>
    <!--<li><a><input type="image" src="act_logo.pnt" name="" id=""></a></li>-->
    <li><a href="#description">Description</a></li>
    <li><a href="#video">Video</a></li>
    <li><a href="#explication">Explication</a></li>
    <li><a href="#top">Top</a></li>
</div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="page2">
<a id="video" class="smooth"></a>
<br><br><br><br>
<h2 class="a">Video explicatif</h2>
<video width="700" height="400" controls>
    <source src="FondationAct1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="FondationAct1.mp4" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this using the z-index css attribute. Give the header a higher z-index than the video player, and it will appear on top of it.

So for example:

`.header { 
  z-index: 3;
}`

`.video-player {
  z-index: 1;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Give it a higher z-index then!

```css
.header {
 padding: none;
 font-size: 20px;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 /*border: 1px dashed orange;*/
 position: fixed;
 height: 90px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #005a84;

 overflow: hidden;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 5;

 list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<div>
    <li href="#top"><img src="act_logo.png"></li>
    <!--<li><a><input type="image" src="act_logo.pnt" name="" id=""></a></li>-->
    <li><a href="#description">Description</a></li>
    <li><a href="#video">Video</a></li>
    <li><a href="#explication">Explication</a></li>
    <li><a href="#top">Top</a></li>
</div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="page2">
<a id="video" class="smooth"></a>
<br><br><br><br>
<h2 class="a">Video explicatif</h2>
<video width="700" height="400" controls>
    <source src="FondationAct1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="FondationAct1.mp4" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to give your header class a z-index like so:

```
    z-index: 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `z-index` property for the `.header`.
The reason your header is hidding behind the videoplayer is because its using position diferent thant static (eg. absolute, relative, fixed), so it now can be "layered" and you need to tell the browser where it should be.

More info https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

This is your example working https://codepen.io/coliveravenegas/pen/XQMzVb